# is there any way to find the incoming relationship property say "rel_name" for which all nodes in a collection have same value?

Tags: neo4j

Each node have multiple incoming relationship with different properties.i want to find the **incoming relationship property say "rel_name**"

> for ALL (x IN nodes(p)) have same value

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (it returns rel_name with count of nodes and collection of nodes):

```
MATCH (a)<-[r]-()
WITH r.rel_name AS name, count(a) AS count, collect(a) AS coll
WHERE count > 1
RETURN name, count, coll
ORDER BY name
```

or this (it returns all duplicated nodes):

```
MATCH (a)<-[r]-()
WITH r.rel_name AS name, count(a) AS count, collect(a) AS coll
WHERE count > 1
UNWIND coll AS c
RETURN c
```